# Vlookup to fetch adjacent value based on earliest date

Tags: excel-formula

I need help to write a code to return values for DF using the ID in the lookup table to fetch value that correspond to the latest date where there are duplications

[image]

Comment: DATABASE      
ID comp emb Value Date  
1 y LS99 2SJ £253 01-Jan-20  
3 y LE4 URT £450 02-Aug-19  
5 y XXX 254 £485 25-Apr-16  
2 y ERT 45 £486 05-Apr-16  
1 y LS99 2SJ £24 05-May-20  
3 y LE4 URT £2 01-Feb-20  
      
      
In the Vlookup table      
      
ID DF     
1 £24     
2 £486     
3 £2     
      
The DF should pick the value from the Database with the latest date.

Comment: Please, edit your question and put this information inside it. See more on https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 0):

Try a array formula, copy below formula and paste in cell `B14` (i'm considering that "DATABASE" are in `A1`), and press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`.

```
=INDEX(
    $D$3:$D$8,
    MATCH(
        $A14 &
        ":" &
        MAX(
            IF(
                $A14 = $A$3:$A$8,
                $E$3:$E$8,
                0
            )
        ),
        $A$3:$A$8 &
        ":" &
        $E$3:$E$8,
        0
    )
)
```